# Updating a MasterViewController after item select

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, master-detail

I have a `SplitViewController` that navigates a new `ViewController` on the `viewDidAppear:` method where the user can select a "project". Once the user has selected a project, that project is availible globally throughout the entire app and the `MasterViewController` should reload its items based on that. So whenever the `ViewController` is dismissed and the `SplitViewController` is visible again, I need to make the `MasterViewController` reload. How is this possible in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either fire off a notification from your project selection controller that your `MasterViewController` picks up and handles accordingly, or you can set up a delegate protocol in your project selection controller, set your master as the delegate, and fire off the delegate callback. There are many tutorials around on setting up delegates or firing/observing `NSNotifications`.

Comment: I went with the notification approach